# Find Unused Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

There is a database I do not have access to create stored procedures or modify any part of.  It has tables with MANY columns, and many of those columns appear not to be used.

I would like to see which columns are used and which are not (every row has `NULL` value in that column).

I know I could manually do:

```
SELECT COUNT([columnX])
FROM [table]
```

for every single column, in every single table I'd like to know about, but there are *hundreds* of tables that may have *hundreds* of columns each. (One table has **786** columns.)

Is there a better way to find what I need with the permissions I have, without creating procedures, installing any tools, etc.

(The database is on SQL Server 2012).

Comment: this can be done by dynamically generating a `SELECT COUNT(<columnId>)` for each column, in every table. It would take some legwork, but you can use DMVs to get the table and column names.  It's not the number of columns or tables, but the size of the tables (number of rows), and whether this is prod or not, that IMO would be the bigger issue.

Comment: I would write two cursors one would be based on `select object_id from sys.tables`
and the other would take that result and use it for another cursor `Select name from sys.Columns where object_id =[Result First]` then you could create the sql string based on both and maybe write every column and table name that was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query I came up with. It gives not only the number of rows which have a value, but also the percent of all rows which have a value in each column.

It is specific to a single table (here called `specifictable`) because I was only interested in the columns of certain tables at the time, and it was easier to change the table name in two places than to make the query do it all itself.

First we declare some variables, get the count of all rows from `specifictable`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @tot INT;
SELECT @tot = COUNT(*) FROM specifictable;
```

Then we concatenate together a big `UNION` SQL statement, separated by newlines (`CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`). It selects the column name, its order in the table, the count of rows with a value in that column, and the percentage of all rows that is.

```
SELECT @sql += ' UNION ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
    + 'SELECT '
        + '''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' as Col, ' + cast(ORDINAL_POSITION as varchar) + ' as OrdinalPosition, '
        + ' count(' + COLUMN_NAME + ') as NumWithVal, '
        + '(count(' + COLUMN_NAME + ') / CAST(' + CAST(@tot as varchar(20)) + ' as decimal) * 100) as Percnt '
    + 'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'specifictable';
```

Because it prepended each individual `SELECT` with a `UNION`, we trim off the entire first line, which only contains "`UNION`", and then add an `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, CHARINDEX(char(10), @sql), LEN(@sql))     -- remove first line (extra union)
SELECT @sql += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'ORDER BY 3 DESC, OrdinalPosition'
```

Finally, it's executed (which requires the `EXEC sp_executesql` permission, which I thankfully have on this database).

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```